# Macbook Battery Charging Troubles

Tags: macbook, battery, battery-life

Problem: 
Occasionally, my macbook's battery will say it's charging and actually won't be. It stays at 0% for a long time.

Other info:
I thought it was my battery (laptop was 3 years old). Got a new battery. Issue did not go away.
Got a new power supply. Did not go away.

Ended up getting a unibody macbook pro. :)
(We even ended up moving to a new house).

Now still having the issue.

The only thing I can think of is my power strip, which is the only thing that has stayed constant. Is it possible for the strip to be affecting the amount of watts my macbook(s) are getting and preventing it from properly charing the battery. I think it goes in and out, the battery picks up the slack and once it's empty the computer shuts down b/c there's no power at all for a second or two.

Funny thing is I have a desktop PC on this same strip and it has never had issues with power.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Have you tried other plugging into other power outlets? Or resetting the SMC on the computer?

Comment: I think you answered your own question.

Comment: Of course he didn't answer his own question: he said the PC don't have the same problem!

Comment: Is there an LED on the charger? Is it green, yellow, or off?

Answer (score 0):

You should isolate all the items from the wall to the laptop. So try a different power strip, and try a different power adaptor. If the power adaptor is a problem, try swapping out the duckhead, checking the cord for damage, etc.